# Two browsers are opening in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using two classes, one is the `BaseCode` in which all the basic methods are declared. The class is defined as follows:

```
package CodeBase;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BaseCode {

    //All the Universal variables for TestBase class are declared here:
        public static WebDriver driver = null;

    //All Universal Methods for TestBase class are declared here:
            public void launchBrowser(String baseUrl) throws Exception{
                try {
                        System.out.println("Launching the Chrome Browser");
                        String driverpath = "E:\\Learning\\Selenium\\Drivers\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe";
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverpath);
                        driver = new ChromeDriver();
                        driver.manage().window().maximize();
                        System.out.println("Opening URL: " + baseUrl);
                        driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }catch(Exception E) {
                System.out.println(E.getMessage() +"\n" + E.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
}
```

Now the second class where I am using the above `launchBrowser()` is as follows:

```
package projectpack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import CodeBase.BaseCode;



public class Flipkart {

    public static BaseCode B = new BaseCode();

  @Test
  public void testFlipkart() {
      String url = "https://www.flipkart.com/";
      try {
            B.launchBrowser(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        this.takeSnapShot(driver, "E://Learning/Selenium/Screenhots/Flipkart/Intro.jpeg");
        String Prod1 = "philips bt120";
        WebElement Search = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._1WMLwI .LM6RPg"));
        Search.sendKeys(Prod1);
        this.takeSnapShot(driver, "E://Learning/Selenium/Screenhots/Flipkart/Step1.jpeg");
        Search.submit();
        this.takeSnapShot(driver, "E://Learning/Selenium/Screenhots/Flipkart/Step2.jpeg");
        WebElement Object = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/a[2]"));
        Object.click();
        this.takeSnapShot(driver, "E://Learning/Selenium/Screenhots/Flipkart/Step3.jpeg");
        driver.quit();
        }catch(Exception E) {
            System.out.println(E.getMessage() + "\n" + E.getStackTrace());
        }
  }
}
```

When I am running this code, its opening two browsers instead of one. The first one is already redirected to flipkart.com but the second one just shows a blank window. The Console output is as follows:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
Launching the Chrome Browser
Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 47688
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 25, 2017 9:58:20 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Opening URL: https://www.flipkart.com/
Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 47270
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 25, 2017 9:58:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._1WMLwI .LM6RPg"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

If it had stayed in the same browser it would have found the `Search` WebElement but its opening the second browser.

Can anyone help on how to stop opening two browsers.

Comment: Step through your code, and you'll immediately see how `new ChromeDriver()` is being called twice. Another suggestion, why not have `Flipkart` extend `BaseCode`? While I generally believe in **composition over inheritance**, I think this is a case where inheritance makes more sense. It would also make it easier to keep track of the `driver` and use it properly so you don't have to pass it around to different classes.

Comment: simply make the object of the baseclass and call it here

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Selenium C# Visual Studio. It turns that I have another class in my project where I had initialized WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); and also had it on my main test_class.

How I resolved it:
I removed it from my Main_class and created an instance of it there and then consumed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the following code twice:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Once in the LaunchBrowser method and once just after the try catch. That's why you get two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialize chrome driver 2 times one in function one in class

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: But then how to use the methods in the `Flipkart` class if I dont initialize the driver. Should I use like this:
`BaseCode.driver.findElement()`
Or is there any other way to use the methods in the `Flipkart` class

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found that I had "@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)"
before all the other testNG annotaions. I didn't had @afterSuite in the code (it probably forget to delete it after one of the tests.

After taking it off it got fixed.